# Cuando agrego la propiedad standalone a un componente la página queda en blanco

Tags: angular, standalone

El código puede verse en [la página oficial](https://angular.io/tutorial/tour-of-heroes/toh-pt1#final-code-review)

- Creé el proyecto con ng new.
- Creé un componente con ng generate.
- Modifiqué un poco los templates y referencié ese componente en el de root.
- Ahora quiero importar **NgFor**, para lo cual me pide que agregue la propiedad **standalone**.
- Lo hago y se borra todo de la pantalla del navegador sin marcar ningún error.

El tutorial parece bastante mediocre. Al principio no avisa que hay que generar el proyecto usando la opción --no-standalone para que se corresponda con el resto de la guía. Ahora esto. ¿Alguna idea?

Me dijeron que el dominio *angular.dev* es más nuevo pero no sé porque no aparece en las búsquedas de google ¿será que está desactualizada la guía que estoy usando?

Comment: *"Ahora quiero importar NgFor, para lo cual me pide que agregue la propiedad standalone."* -> Esto me parece raro. Primero que nada por qué quieres importar `ngFor` en un componente que no es ya standalone?? La directiva ngFor está incluida en el commons, que suele (o debe) estar importado en tu módulo principal. Segundo... añadir la propiedad `standalone: true` a un componente tiene MUCHOS "efectos secundarios", no puedes simplemente añadirla y pretender que siga funcionando. Te recomiendo que repases bien la documentación (si usas una de las últimas versiones de angular, usa angular.dev! )

Comment: Está claramente desactualizado enl a página que estoy usando. Piden que importe NgFor y que, dentro de @Component, asigne true a standalone y declare el import de NgFor. Sin hacer el import funcionó bien pero la próxima dificultad que me encuentre me paso a angular.dev entonces. Gracias por tu ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como se dijo en los comentarios, ya no es necesario importar NgFor como se pide en el tutorial. Se omite esa parte y funciona correctamente.

Para versiones nuevas de Angular, conviene usar la documentación de [angular.dev](https://angular.dev), según dicen.